# Passing Extra data over android custom alert dialog

Tags: java, android

I want to put phone number from editText to custom alert dialog when i click "NEXT" like this :
[image: 1]
I have been put getStringExtra to textView custom dialog but i should click "Yes", then number success displayed. But what i want is when i click "NEXT", number displayed.

Code :

```
public void sendVerificationCode() {
    phoneNumber = countryCode.getFullNumberWithPlus(); // The number i want to display to custom alert dialog

    Intent moveVerification = new Intent(CreateUserActivity.this, VerificationCode.class);
    moveVerification.putExtra("sendPhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    startActivity(moveVerification);
    finish();
}

public void dialogVerification() {
    dialogVerification = new Dialog(CreateUserActivity.this);
    dialogVerification.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogVerification.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
    dialogVerification.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    Button buttonYes = dialogVerification.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
    Button buttonEdit = dialogVerification.findViewById(R.id.buttonEdit);
    TextView displayNumber = dialogVerification.findViewById(R.id.displayNumber); // I want to display the number at here

    dialogVerification.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialogVerification.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogVerification.show();
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: i was edited @KishanMaurya

Comment: I don't see the calling of `dialogVerification` function in your code. If the function `dialogVerification` is called to show dialog, just send `phoneNumber` to the function like `dialogVerification(String phoneNumber)` then set TextView value like `displayNumber.setText(phoneNumber)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **If** your code is in the same activity:

Either pass the `phoneNumber` as a parameter to the `dialogVerification()` or declare it as a global variable to use it in any function directly.

1. To pass it as a parameter:

   call `dialogVerification()` as from `sendVerificationCode()` :

   `dialogverification(phoneNumber);`

and replace this -> `public void dialogVerification() {`

with

`public void dialogVerification(int phoneNumber) {`

And simply put the phone number in the textView as

`displayNumber.setText(phoneNumber.toString());`

2. Declaring it as a global variable:
   declare the phoneNumber before the `onStart()` just below the class declaration as `int phonNumber;`

And simply put the phone number in the textView as

`displayNumber.setText(phoneNumber.toString());`

- **Else** if this `dialogVerification` is in another `VerificationCode`

pass it to the other activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUserActivity.this, VerificationCode.class);
intent.putExtra("Phone_Number", phoneNumber);
startActivity(intent);
```

and access that number in `VerificationCode` as:

```
int phoneNumber= getIntent().getIntExtra("Phone_Number");
```

And simply put the phone number in the textView as

`displayNumber.setText(phoneNumber.toString());`

**PS:** It it's a string, just replace every `int` with `String`, `getIntExtra` as `getStringExtra` and remove that `.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText phonenum;
Button next;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    phonenum = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    next = findViewById(R.id.button);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            go();
        }
    });

}
void go(){
    String somenumber = String.valueOf(phonenum.getText());
    AlertDialog dialog;
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Number verification");
    alertDialog.setMessage(somenumber + "\n" + "is your number above correct ?");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //call function to start next activity
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog = alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **static class** and create a **static field** to hold your **phoneNumber** variable value. Then you can access your phoneNumber variable anywhere.
Not a best practice, but this way always work out

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the View Binding in android latest version.

I customized the Alert Dialog and passed the required values to the dialog.

```
private ConnectDialogBinding connectDialogBinding;
private String chargerID;

private void connectDialog() {
    // Create the object of
    // AlertDialog Builder class
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConnectActivity.this);
    connectDialogBinding = ConnectDialogBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    builder.setView(connectDialogBinding.getRoot());
    connectDialogBinding.txtID.setText(chargerID);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    // Create the Alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    // Show the Alert Dialog box
    alertDialog.show();

    connectDialogBinding.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DMON.png)